# Modify timestamp in datatime field in DB2

Tags: db2

Is there a way to modify the timestamp alone for an existing datetime attribute, for example changedate currently holds the value `2002-10-18 00:00:00.0` and would like to change it to `2002-10-18 08:00:00.0` The date would remain the same and time would only change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the time portion of the timestamp is 00:00:00... and you want it to be a a set difference away, then you can simply add the appropriate number of hours (and/or minutes and or seconds)

```
-- just updating the hour
update myTable
set myTS = myTs + 8 hours;

-- updating hour, minutes, seconds
update mytable
set myTS = myTs + 8 hours + 35 minutes + 22 seconds;
```

If it's possible that the time portion has something besides 00:00:00, then you can make use the scalar `timestamp()` function which returns a timestamp from individual date and time parameters.

```
update mytable
set myTS = timestamp(date(myTS), time('08:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular UPDATE statement, then set the column value to the new timestamp value. To do so, you could utilize the date / time / timestamp-related scalar functions.

Not tested, but something like:

```
new value = DATE(timestamp_column)+ 8 HOURS
```

It would extract the date portion and add the 8 hours. Else, use [TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-timestamp-format) to compose the new value by extracting what you need and pass it in.